How to prove a multi-resolution analysis $V_j: j\in \mathbb Z$ intersects to zero
Suppose that $V_j: j\in \mathbb Z$ is an increasing sequence of subspaces of $L^2(\mathbb R),$ such that $f\in V_0$ iff $f(2^j \cdot)\in V_j.$ Assume also that $\{\phi(\cdot -n): n\in \mathbb Z\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V_0.$ How to prove that $\bigcap_{j\in \mathbb Z} V_j = \varnothing$? This seems an obvious fact that everybody assumes without proof in books I read, and I am trying to find one.
